# who to have rtl support in React Native in some pages and components and not affect the whole app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on an App and set the allow rtl to false

```
 sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), false);
```

now I have a material ui text field that needs to be rtl in some pages but when I set i18manager force rtl in ComponentDidMount it forces the whole app to have rtl I just need it in some pages

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!I18nManager.isRTL) {
      I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
    }
  }
```

note: the textfield direction rtl doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change one component to RTL. I would suggest you to go with `flexDirection:'row-reverse'` and `textAlign:'right'`.